# Missing notification sounds in android 5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications

I wanted extra notification sounds in my android 5 device (Micromax Canvas Tab P290). After rooting, I added some ogg files to `/system/media/audio/`. For unknown reason, all the notification sounds are missing from the apps. The notification sound list is empty. I have been careful about the permissions. All permissions are `755` for directories and `644` for files.

Also worth noting is that screen lock sound and touch sounds work. Alarms (from the stock Clock app), notification tones from apps (WhatsApp, Hike or similar apps) do not list any sound files.

Can anyone give some pointers as to why this might happen? Below are a couple of screenshots: [Missing alarm sounds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhdBG.png) and [Missing notfication sounds in Hike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uQes.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally resorted to factory reset. Happy it worked. Sad that nobody knew how to fix it.